# Merge SELECT and SHOW query

Tags: mysql

Can I merge the result of SELECT query and SHOW statement?

For example - need to get answer in one table for:

```
 select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

and

```
 show create view `v1`
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  But the following query will give a similar result:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(
 "CREATE",
 -- can't get ALGORITHM
 " DEFINER = '",
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(DEFINER, '@', 1), "'@'", SUBSTRING_INDEX(DEFINER, '@', -1), "'",
 " SQL SECURITY ", SECURITY_TYPE,
 " VIEW `", REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, "`", "``"), "`",
 " AS ", VIEW_DEFINITION,
 IF(CHECK_OPTION <> "NONE", CONCAT(" WITH ", CHECK_OPTION, " CHECK OPTION"), "")
) AS `CREATE`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good method, but unfortunately - the only reason to use 'show create view' - is to get information about ALGORITHM, as I understood it is the only way.

Comment: @YuriyVelichko: AFAIK, the only other way is to delve into MySQL's `.frm` definition file for the view.  See [this blog](http://rpbouman.blogspot.co.uk/2006/05/mysql-view-metadata-original-source.html) for more information.  I suspect parsing the `SHOW` output in your application may end up being easier.

Comment: Thanks for link! And yes - parse SHOW output is better way.